# Run VS Code task on specific file/folder selectable via a drop-down list

Tags: visual-studio-code, task, customization

I am trying to figure out how to run a  VS Code task on a specific folder/file that is selectable over a drop-down list.

Example:

1. open Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P)
2. filter on 'tasks' -> select 'Tasks: Run Tasks'
3. Select the task to run, e.g. Cpplint
4. NEW PART: now instead of executing it right away, there should open up a drop-down list to select the folder/file you want to run the task on or you can select 'all' and it works as before and the task is run on all folders, beginning at the root (here: src) folder.

structure:

```
ws
|   
+-- .env
|   |  
|   +-- ...
|    
+-- src
    |  
    +-- dir1
    |   |
    |   +-- file 1.1
    |   +-- ... 
    |   +-- file 1.n
    +-- dir2
    |   |
    |   +-- file 2.1
    |   +-- ... 
    |   +-- file 2.n 
    |   +-- dir2.2
    |       |
    |       +-- file 2.2.1
    |       +-- ...
    |       +-- file 2.2.n 
    +-- ...
    |
    +-- dirn
        |
        +-- file n.1 
        +-- ...
```

Is there a way to make this work?
If not, is there another way to make something similar work? Thank you for your help.

**Further Questions:**
I was trying to run multiple linters at once with a task "Lint all". This task depends on two other tasks. To avoid parallel execution "Lint all" has "dependsOrder": "sequence", but somehow the drop-down list just appears for the first sub-task. Also just the first sub-task gets executed and then the execution stops. Now I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to get the drop-down list for every sub-task?
2. Is there a way to get the drop-down list just for the first sub-task and then the following sub-tasks remember the input an execute automatically with that?

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Lint all",
            "detail": "Run all linters",
            "dependsOrder": "sequence",
            "dependsOn":["Cpplint", "Pylint"],
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "label": "Cpplint",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cpplint --recursive ${input:selectDir}",
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "label": "Pylint",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "pylint ${input:selectDir}",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "selectDir",
            "type": "command",
            "command": "extension.commandvariable.pickStringRemember",
            "args": {
                "description": "Which directory to Lint?",
                "options": [
                    ["All", "src/"],
                    ["Rerun task", "${remember:toRemember}"],
                    ["Pick directory", "${pickFile:directory}"]
                ],
                "default": null,
                "pickFile": {
                    "directory": {
                        "description": "Which directory?",
                        "include": "src/**",
                        "showDirs": true,
                        "keyRemember":"toRemember"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `${input}` variable

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "cpp lint",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "cpplint ${input:selectDir}"
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "selectDir",
      "type": "pickString",
      "description": "What directory to lint?",
      "options": [
        {"label": "All", "value": "" },
        "dir1",
        "dir2",
        "dir3"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**Edit**

With the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) v1.35.0 you can get a dynamic list of directories.

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "cpp lint",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "cpplint ${input:selectDir}"
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "selectDir",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.pickStringRemember",
      "args": {
        "description": "Which directory to Lint for C++?",
        "options": [
          ["Use previous directory", "${remember:srcSubDir}"],
          ["All", "all"],
          ["Pick directory", "${pickFile:srcSubDir}"]
        ],
        "default": null,
        "pickFile": {
          "srcSubDir": {
            "description": "Which directory?",
            "include": "src/**/*.{cpp,h}",
            "showDirs": true,
            "keyRemember": "srcSubDir"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you pick a `src` sub directory you get the full path of the directory. I have created an issue to get results [relative to workspace](https://github.com/rioj7/command-variable/issues/32). You can use the `extension.commandvariable.transform` command to remove the workspace folder part.

---

**Edit 2**

In Command Variable v1.35.1:

- Fixed the storing of raw value in `pickStringRemember`. Now the value after variable substitution is stored.
- Fixed the escaping of the `pickString` and `pickFile` UI to abort the task.
- Add a property in example to `pickFile` to store the picked file under a name
- Add an option in example to `pickString` to use/remember the previous `pickFile`
- Add a `default` property to example in `pickString` to escape the UI

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick answer! Is there also a possibility to make it dynamic? Since in my case I have a src folder where I'm creating subfolders....so that I don't have to manually add them to the tasks.json file.

Also how does "label": "All" work in this case? selecting 'All' just gets me '> Executing task: cpplint  <'. Do I have to create another task called 'All' (tried it but without success)

Comment: @Julian what is command to run the cpplint on the whole workspace? if you select label `All` the result of the pick is the string for property `value` (here the empty string), edit the question to specify the commands used to cpplint the different cases. The dynamic part I will get back to that.

Comment: sorry for bothering you again, but there are two more things I can't figure out.  
1) when pressing 'esc' the task gets still executed (> Executing task: pylint Escaped <) and doesn't just quit. Is that an issue with the extension I can't do much about?  
2) Is there a possibility to re-run the exact same task with the previously selected parameters? I know there is 'Tasks: Rerun Last Task' but the problem with this is that I have to pick the parameters again (this would be a problem if there were lots of hundreds of subfolders I have to look through again)

Comment: @Julian See my Edit2, you can define a separate task to rerun with the previous dir by using the command `extension.commandvariable.remember` with `"args": { "key": "srcSubDir" }`

Comment: hello, after trying to create something a little more complex I encountered some problems. I edited my question ( -> 'Further questions') to explain my issue. Maybe you can also help me here?

Comment: @Julian In my setup both tasks run, but the pylint task gets the same value as the cpplint task, as if VSC remembers the value of a variable, if I make a copy of the `pickFileRemember` input names `selectDir3` and use this in the pylint task I get a second dir selection. The tasks in a sequence should work the same as starting the tasks yourself. You should file an issue at the VSC repo. You can use `${remember:srcSubDir}` anywhere you like in the task or launch config files. As long as the pick is run before.

Comment: When executing ["Pick directory", "${pickFile:srcSubDir}"] it is possible to do ["Use previous directory", "${remember:srcSubDir}"] and the exact same task is run again. But how can I do it for ["All", "all"], since there the pick isn't saved to rerun the task, so ["Use previous directory", "${remember:srcSubDir}"] isn't working (I know that in this case I could just use ["All", "all"] again, but it would be nice if rerun last pick would also work here).

Comment: FYI I created an issue at the VSC repo for running tasks in a sequence and the behavior that tasks in a sequence aren't working the same as starting the tasks yourself is as designed.....
"We intentionally ask only once since for most input variables asking multiple times is redundant: users usually want to use the same value.

If you want to ask more than once you'll need to define multiple input variables."